# Sending an image (png) from my back (Java spring) to the front (react) and printing it

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, node.js, blob

We're encountering difficulties displaying images fetched from a Java Spring backend in a React frontend. Despite successfully retrieving the image data from the backend, we're unable to render it in the  tag on the frontend.

here is what my back send:

```java
   @PostMapping("/getProduct/{type}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getProduct(@PathVariable("type") String productName) {
        String filePath = DIRECTORY_UPLOAD + PRODUCTS + File.separator;
        List<File> files = findAllFile(filePath);


        File productFile = files.stream()
                .filter(f -> f.getName().contains(productName))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if (productFile != null && productFile.exists()) {
            try {
                byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(productFile.toPath());

                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                        .body(imageBytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Handle exception appropriately
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
            }
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }
    }
```

and how my front treat it :

```js
 getImage(type: string): Promise<Response> {

    return axios.post("api" + PATH_UPLOAD +"/getProduct/" + type.replace("/",""), {
      headers: {
        ...authHeader(),
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },

    });
  }
```

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImage = async () => {

            await ProductsService.getImage(data.type).then(async res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    const file = new Blob([res.data], {
                        type: "image/png",
                    });
                    //Build a URL from the file
                    let fileurl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    console.log(fileurl);
                    setProductImgURL(fileurl);

                }

            } )
        } ;
        fetchImage();
    } , []);
```

```
         {
                                    productImgURL === "" ? "" : <img src={productImgURL} alt="Image Produit" className="image"  style={{width: "25%", height: "25%"}}/>
                                }
```

Verified backend endpoint functionality by inspecting network requests and responses.
Implemented frontend logic to fetch image data and render it in the  tag.
Ensured error handling in both frontend and backend code.
Used different way to create a blob, and tried directly printing res.data

Comment: You should encode and decode your image with base64 encoding. There might be control characters in it.

Comment: Just to duplicate what @madgangmixers said, in my experience if you want to get an image in JavaScript and you're not using an `img` tag, you need to base64 encode it.

Comment: you encode it in the backend (function getProduct) and decode it in the frontend (in the 'if (res.status === 200) {' block )